# Dynamically recreating javascript function on update

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have some C# code that dynamically builds a javascript function on my asp.net page:

```
        string addresses = "function doAddresses() {" + Environment.NewLine;
        addresses = addresses + "var hostAddress = new Array();" + Environment.NewLine;
        //int i = 0;
        //int timeOut = 2;
        foreach (BusinessLayer.HostApplication host in hosts)
        {
            //if (host.Address1.Contains("5208 "))
            //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            var location = new BusinessLayer.HostLocations();
            location.GetByHostApplicationId(host.HostApplicationId);
            if (location.Count == 0)
                continue;
            addresses = addresses + string.Format("placePin({0}, {1}, '{3}', {4});{2}", location[0].Longitude, location[0].Latitude, Environment.NewLine, (host.Address1 + " " + host.FStreetSuffixId.StreetSuffixName.Replace("'", "\\'") + ", " + host.City + ", " + host.FStateId.StateAbbreviation).Replace("'", "\\'"),host.IsActive);

        }
        addresses = addresses + "}" + Environment.NewLine;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "markers", addresses, true);
```

This part is working fine. Now on my ASP.NET page, I have a jQuery function that executes on load and calls this dynamic function:

```
$(function() {
    doAddresses();
});
```

Again, this works fine. Now what I'm trying to do is I have a hyperlink button on my page that does an Ajax call using jQuery. This works fine, and after the Ajax call, an update panel gets updated:

```
$('a[id^=hypCat]').click(function () {
   var mnuId = $(this).attr("id").replace("hypCat", "");
   $('#<%= hfCategoryId.ClientID %>').val(mnuId);
   __doPostBack('<%= updHostsTable.ClientID %>', '');
   doAddresses();
```

});

Everything works, except since my `doAddresses()` function is out of date. Apparently, the C# `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` function is not updating the javascript. This might not even be possible because I'm not sure if javascript code is something that can be taken out and inserted from the DOM like an HTML element.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible and how to achieve it? Or guide me down an alternate way to do this?

Comment: Try adding variable part of the function as arguments to `doAddresses` function and call with updated information.

Comment: @Vega -- The problem is, my arguments come from my C# code. If you look inside my `foreach` statement up above, its calling a `placePin` function with all the arguments. So, I would still need a way to do this to get the arguments that I need.

Comment: Instead of writing the function, build the data in C# that will be later consumed by the Javascript function. Then use that data and call the function so that you call always call the function with updated information. I am not able to see the full picture here so not sure if it is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that `__doPostBack` performs an asynchronous request, and `doAddresses` is triggered immediately after. It will execute before the script has returned and created a new function with the right data, rather than waiting for the new function to come before executing.

---

I'm going to be blunt - this just seems like sloppy architecture. Why pass back an entire JavaScript function, and not just the data for the function? You could restructure like so:

```
function doAddresses(dataArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    placePin(dataArray[0], dataArray[1], dataArray[2], dataArray[3]);
  }
}
```

Enumerating the data points in the code has no real advantage, and obscures the meaning of what's happening. It would be better if you replaced the function that generates 'doAddress' on the server with something that just generates an array of arguments for placePin, and returns the [serialized] array to the client.

---

Now, that doesn't quite fix the problem, but with a little jQuery magic this can be made to work. The goal now is to get an array of values from the server to pin, then execute `doAddresses` once the server has responded with the data.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
var data = $('a[id^=hypCat]').closest('form').serializeArray();
data.push({ name: '__EVENTTARGET', value: '<%= updHostsTable.ClientID %>' })
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(responseData) {
    doAddresses(responseData);
  }  
});
```

I don't know quite how practical this will be for you - you may already have some better way to deal with an async callback function. I don't quite know the spread of functions that you'd see in a typical ASP.NET frontend - ideally, they'd have some better async complements to `__doPostBack`, and you can make this drop-in a little more smoothly (I think the above jQuery code has a few too many hacks).

Comment: Its okay to be blunt. This is code I inherited, not created lol. I agree that the architecture of the code needs revisited one day.